# How to combine TouchableOpacity Props type with additional fields

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I'm trying to add a `color` prop to a `styled-components` wrapped `TouchableOpacity` and get flow to type it properly.

```
type TouchableOpacityProps = $PropertyType<Element<TouchableOpacity>, "props">;
type ButtonTouchableProps = { color: string } & TouchableOpacityProps;

const ButtonTouchable: ComponentType<ButtonTouchableProps> = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
`;
```

However, I'm getting this flow warning when using `<ButtonTouchable color="#CCCCCC" />`:

> Cannot create `ButtonTouchable` element because property `color` is
>   missing in object type [1] but exists in props [2]. (References: [1] [2])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// @flow
import { type ElementConfig, type ComponentType } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

type ButtonTouchableProps = {|
  ...$Exact<ElementConfig<typeof TouchableOpacity>>,
  color: string,
|};

const ButtonTouchable: ComponentType<ButtonTouchableProps> = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
`;
```

Comment: `ElementConfig` is what I was missing. Thanks!